# CodeIgniter form validation, show errors in order

Tags: php, codeigniter

Lets say I have a login form and it has fields username and password. Both of the fields are required to be filled in and when you submit the form it has two different lines for them.

Username field is required.
Password field is required.

What I want to do is to show only the username field errors and when they don't have any errors with username field, it will show the password field errors.

How would this be done?

Also, I remember there is a way to show errors only regarding a field, what was the snippet for it?

Comment: I really don't know where to start. The way I think is check if there are any username validation errors then if no show the password, but that wouldn't be a good code practice. So I wanted to know if there is a neater more codeigniter like way of doing this. If no, then no worries, I will use individual field errors to accomplish something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a custom callback function tied to just one input, that checks both inputs and conditionally sets the desired message.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class YourController extends CI_Controller {

    public function save() 
    {
        //.... Your controller method called on submit

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        // Build validation rules array
        $validation_rules = array(
                                array(
                                    'field' => 'username',
                                    'label' => 'Username',
                                    'rules' => 'trim|xss_clean|callback_required_inputs'
                                    ),
                                array(
                                    'field' => 'password',
                                    'label' => 'Password',
                                    'rules' => 'trim|xss_clean'
                                    )
                                );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($validation_rules);
        $valid = $this->form_validation->run();

        // Handle $valid success (true) or failure (false)
        if($valid)
        {
            //
        }
        else
        {
            //
        }
    }


    public function required_inputs()
    {
        if( ! $this->input->post('username'))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('required_inputs', 'The Username field is required');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else if ($this->input->post('username') AND ! $this->input->post('password'))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('required_inputs', 'The Password field is required');
            return FALSE;
        }

        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: good approach, I conceptually thought about this. Ended up using the normal way with just more css styling